# Trouble with React Router in deploy

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am running into some issues when I try to deploy my react app. On my local machine, everything runs just fine. When I deploy it, however, the links don't work when I manually type them in or when I do a refresh. They do work if I click on buttons on the page though

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(9000);
```

Here is my `server.js` which is intended to make every request go to `index.html`:

```
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

The `index.js` section:

```
let content = (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about-us/"><AboutUs/></Route>
           ...
          <Redirect from="/" to="/homepage/1"/>
          <Route ><PageNotFound /></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
```

and my app.js

Comment: It means you don't implement server-side rendering. Do you use CRA?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this issue I had to add history. To fix this, in `src` folder create file `history.js` with code of

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

Next `yarn add history` or `npm install history`.

In your `app.js` file you will then `import history from "./history"` and add `history` to `Router` like so:

```
let content = (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about-us/"><AboutUs/></Route>
           ...
          <Redirect from="/" to="/homepage/1"/>
          <Route ><PageNotFound /></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
```